# How do I parse text by line in an Azure Logic App?

Tags: azure, parsing, azure-logic-apps

I've got a Logic App that reads in an email from a form submission. Unfortunately, I only have access to the email and not where the form results are stored, so I currently have the Logic App set up to pull in the email and convert it to text.

If it was just one field, I assume I could just grab it all, throw it in a variable and split it to get what I need, but I'm not sure how to do this with multiple lines.

The emails always come in with this format:

---

Date: 08/18/2022

Time: 09:30:00

Requestor Name: Robert Bobson

Requestor Email: bob@companyname.com

Requestor Phone Number: 800-867-5309

Site Name: CompanyName

Site Number: 123456789

---

Am I able to set a line index and then grab everything on that line and then split it before assigning it to a variable? Is this going to require RegEx or is there a workaround or expression in Logic Apps that will handle this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement using expressions.

First, try removing the extra lines from the given email. below is the expression I'm using to achieve the same.

```
split(outputs('Compose'),'\n\n')
```

The above expression results in:
[image]

> Am I able to set a line index and then grab everything on that line and then split it before assigning it to a variable?

yes, This is possible using the below expression

```
outputs('Compose_2')?[0] gives the Date 
outputs('Compose_2')?[1] gives the Time
...
```

**RESULTS:**

[image]

Alternatively, You can convert the string into Parsable Json and then Parse it through Parse JSON Action. Below is the flow of my Logic App

[image]

In the above step I'm extracting the values on both left and right sides and storing them into a variable. You can use either of slice or substring functions to extract the values.

[image]

In the next step I'm trying to Parse the values through Parse JSON action.

**RESULTS:**

[image]

You can test the same using below code view in your logicapp

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "Date: 08/18/2022\n\nTime: 09:30:00\n\nRequestor Name: Robert Bobson\n\nRequestor Email: bob@companyname.com\n\nRequestor Phone Number: 800-867-5309\n\nSite Name: CompanyName\n\nSite Number: 123456789",
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Compose_2": {
                "inputs": "@split(outputs('Compose'),'\n\n')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Compose_3": {
                "inputs": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['Site Name']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "length",
                            "type": "integer"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Json",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@concat('{',substring(variables('Json'),0,sub(length(variables('Json')),1)),'}')",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "Date": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Requestor Email": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Requestor Name": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Requestor Phone Number": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Site Name": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Site Number": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Time": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Until": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "Until": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_string_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "Json",
                            "value": "@{outputs('Current_Object')},"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Current_Object": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "AppendToStringVariable"
                    },
                    "Current_Object": {
                        "inputs": "\"@{substring(outputs('Compose_2')?[variables('length')],0,indexOf(outputs('Compose_2')?[variables('length')],':'))}\":\"@{slice(outputs('Compose_2')?[variables('length')],add(indexOf(outputs('Compose_2')?[variables('length')],':'),2),length(outputs('Compose_2')?[variables('length')]))}\"",
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Compose"
                    },
                    "Increment_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "length",
                            "value": 1
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Append_to_string_variable": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "IncrementVariable"
                    }
                },
                "expression": "@equals(variables('length'), length(outputs('Compose_2')))",
                "limit": {
                    "count": 60,
                    "timeout": "PT1H"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Until"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {},
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: I ended up using the first method you outlined above before I saw this response, but I think the JSON solution is much more elegant and may pivot to that instead. Thank you so much for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can Convert the email body using "Html To Text" action and then assign it to an array variable by using the split expression for any delimiter.